# How to get data from 2 tables in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, database, join, left-join

Assume that I have 2 tables : members and orders (Mysql)

```
Members : 
id   |   name
1    |   Lee
2    |   brad
Orders : 
id   |   member_id   |   status (1: paid, 2: unpaid)   |    total
1    |   1           |   1                             |   1000000 
2    |   1           |   1                             |   1500000
3    |   1           |   2                             |   1300000
4    |   2           |   1                             |   3000000 
5    |   2           |   2                             |   3500000
6    |   2           |   2                             |   3300000
```

I have a sql query :

```
SELECT m.name,
       o.member_id,
       COUNT(o.id)  AS number_of_order,
       SUM(o.total) AS total2
FROM   orders o
       LEFT JOIN members m
              ON o.member_id = m.id
GROUP  BY o.member_id
```

which give me this:

```
name   |   number_of_order   |   total2
Lee    |   3                 |   3800000
brad   |   3                 |   9800000
```

All that I want is something like this :

```
    name   |   number_of_order   |   total2
           |  Paid        Unpaid | Paid      Unpaid
    ------------------------------------------------
    Lee    |         3           |   3800000
           |  2             1    | 2500000   1300000
    ------------------------------------------------
    brad   |         3           |   9800000
           |  1             2    | 3000000   6800000
    ------------------------------------------------
```

How to make a query that can give me that result?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: In your select query m.name is not part of group by clause so how will it work?

Comment: It's my typo mistake. I updated my question. Thanks for noticing me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use conditions in the `SUM/COUNT` functions.

```
SELECT 
  m.name,
  COUNT(o.id) AS number_of_order,
  SUM(o.total) AS total2,
  COUNT(IF(o.status=1, 1, NULL)) AS paid_order,
  COUNT(IF(o.status=2, 1, NULL)) AS unpaid_order,
  SUM(IF(o.status=1, o.total, 0)) AS paid,
  SUM(IF(o.status=2, o.total, 0)) AS unpaid
FROM orders o 
LEFT JOIN members m ON o.member_id=m.id
GROUP BY o.member_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try listing the orders table multiple times with different aliases and where clauses. Something like:

```
SELECT m.name,
       COUNT(po.id),
       COUNT(uo.id),
       COUNT(o.id),
       SUM(po.total),
       SUM(uo.total),
       SUM(o.total)
FROM   members m,
       orders o,
       orders po,
       orders uo
WHERE  o.member_id = m.id
       AND po.member_id = m.id
       AND uo.member_id = m.id
       AND po.status = 1
       AND uo.status = 2
GROUP  BY m.name
```

It's not exactly what you asked for, but it should get you moving in the right direction.

Comment: Notice the table aliases. Each will work independently of the other. I prefer your solution though.

Comment: I edited to factor in all orders too, but i still prefer your solution,.

Comment: I should have used outer joins too, but the result will be the same given the two users had both paid and unpaid orders in the example dataset. Otherwise, it would have have omitted the member not having both.